# jquery animate stop, wait for a while and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mechanism that move element place to place by queue position that pop every time animate fire.

I want the animate to wait for a fixed time, and after that to allow animate again.

```
    $("#" + elemId).animate({
        top: that.CallsQueue.pop()
    }, that.SecondForEntireTrack, function () {

    });
    //here i want to implement waiting befor another animat huppen
```

Comment: Share what you tried to implement. If it is a time interval based waiting, you can setTimeout as answered by @martin

Answer (score 2):

Use two animations.

```
$("#" + elemId).animate(
    {
        top: that.CallsQueue.pop()
    },
    that.SecondForEntireTrack,
    function () {
        secondAnimation(elemId, that);
    }
);

function secondAnimation(elemId, that) {
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        $("#" + elemId).animate(
            {
                left: that.CallsQueue.pop()
        },
        that.SecondForEntireTrack
     },
     800000
   );
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `setTimeout(function (){}, time)` function.
More informations here -> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp